# Orbeon Forms Builder custom persistence API: Why does it call /crud/.../data/data.xml?

Tags: orbeon

I am currently implementing my own persistence layer for Orbeon Forms. As far as I have understood the [virtual hierachy of data](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api#TOC-Virtual-hierarchy-of-data), creating a form with Form Builder in the application "myapp" with the name "myform" should cause the form builder to call

/crud/myapp/myform/form/form.xhtml, passing the newly created form as HTTP-PUT data. Thus I created a spring method annotated with:

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/crud/{applicationName}/{formName}/form/form.xhtml")
public void saveForm(@PathVariable String formName, @RequestBody String putData)
```

I expected this method to be called with my form. But this method does not get called. Instead the method

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/crud/{applicationName}/{formName}/data/{uuid}/data.xml")
public void saveInstance(@PathVariable String uuid, @RequestBody String putData)
```

gets called. `putData` contains the full XHTML form. Why is this happening? I thought that the second URL would only be called for saving an instance, more specifically the `<xforms:instance id="fr-form-instance">` part of a form, once I fill in values for a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the form definition can be in two places:

1. When you *edit* it with Form Builder, the form definition is just form data as far as the builder is concerned. So it's stored as `data.xml` for `orbeon/builder`.
2. When you *publish* it, it is copied to (HTTP PUT) `form.xhtml` for `myapp/myform`. It is also read from there (HTTP GET) when the form definition is needed to view/edit/search data associated with that form.

You can easily verify this by publishing the form.

The good news is that you need 1 above anyway to handle form data for published forms.

Note that form definitions and form data can both have attachments as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well the manual does not say so explicitly, but you should look a little closer at your the URL that is actually called: `/crud/orbeon/builder/data/<some uuid>/data.xml`. You see how this actually is a saving the form as an instance associated with the orbeon builder and that it is not your form beeing saved?

After this method has completed you can press "publish" which will call the desired saveForm method above.